# Can't cd in a ruby script

Tags: ruby

Can anyone please explain why the following snippet doesn't work?

```
@t=`mktemp -d`
puts @t
at_exit {system "rm -rf #{@t}"}

begin
  Dir.chdir @t
rescue
  puts $!
  sleep 2
  retry
end
```

Basically, not even repeated attempts at `cd`ing into the newly created temp directory work, yet while the code is inside the `retry` loop, I can perfectly well `cd` into it from a different terminal. 
(The `at_exit` part works -- if I break the `retry` loop with `Ctrl-C`, the directory gets removed).

I have even tried  switching between `Dir.chdir` and `FileUtils.cd` and running the script with several versions of ruby (>=1.9.3), all to no avail.

Comment: FWIW Ruby has [Dir::mktmpdir](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/tmpdir/rdoc/Dir.html#method-c-mktmpdir) for this.

Comment: Thanks. That's useful information. I was looking for it but couldn't find it.

Comment: It certainly looks more clean, though I did run some benchmarks and the overhead associated with external commands vs native ruby functions seemed practically negligible unless you're running huge loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call chomp on the evaluated shell command `mktemp -d` else `Dir.chdir` would be trying to change directory into a directory with new line character

```
t = `mktemp -d`
t #=> /tmp/tmp.4g680eJndT
Dir.chdir t.chomp #Note that you need to strip the new line character that comes with the evaluated shell command
Dir.pwd #=> /tmp/tmp.4g680eJndT
```

Comment: Thank you very much, kind Sir. I will mark your answer as my accepted just as soon as the 2 additional minutes that SO requires me to wait are over.  ;-)